# How to remove white substance from spray painted MDF?

Tags: painting, cleaning, paint-removal

There is a substance that has been left on some cabinets (which are spray painted MDF). The substance is white, and could be paint, or some kind of filler, caulk or putty.

What's the safest way to get this off without damaging the cabinet paintwork?

I have tried scraping it off very lightly with a knife but that doesn't work.

Comment: We'd need pictures to have a good opinion, but plastic razor blades might help.

Comment: What sort of paint finish do the cabinets have? 2-pack? or something DIY?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure. I believe it is spray painted MDF, and of a very high durability (maybe floor-grade paint) -  that's what I remember the installers saying anyway.